# How can solve error which is "'BrowserRouter' is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have installed react-router-dom with version : react-router-dom@6.18.0.
I can't understand why the error keep promting. Error content is below.
Anybody can help what is the problem?

```
[eslint] 
src/App.js
  Line 11:6:  'BrowserRouter' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

```
import './App.css';
import Server from './Component/Server'
import { BrowserRouter as Routes, Router,Route} from "react-router-dom";
import SignIn from './Component/SignIn'

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
      <Server/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Server />} />
        <Route path="/SignIn" element={<SignIn />}/>
      </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm trying to use BrowserRouter to switch the screen asynchronously when click the menu tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In your import statement, you have aliased BrowserRouter as Routes, and you are using BrowserRouter in your component. You should write like this:-*

```
<Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Server />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Server />} />
          <Route path="/SignIn" element={<SignIn />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
```